# How to handle process blocking in SQL Server Profiler?

Tags: sql-server, profiler, blocking

I have run a SQL Profiler Trace which detected a process blocking. Now what should i do, if it always brings the same blocking event, each time duration is getting bigger. I have only one transaction which created a block, and I want it to be fixed in a trace only once, why it keeps repeating?
[image]
Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure that this is a great use for Profiler. Have a look at this article: [When To Use Blocked Processes Reports](http://michaeljswart.com/2011/05/when-to-use-blocked-processes-reports/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Blocked Process Report](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/event-classes/blocked-process-report-event-class?view=sql-server-2017) event class indicates that a task has been blocked for more than a specified amount of time.

To configure the [Blocked Process Threshold](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/blocked-process-threshold-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-2017) and frequency at which reports are generated, use the sp_configure command to configure the blocked process threshold option, which can be set in seconds. The threshold can be set from 0 to 86,400.